# Importance of NN weight precision and precision of mathematic weights

Tags: floating-point, neural-network, wolfram-mathematica

Hi I reworded my question to try to make the answer apply to more people but what I want to know is: What is the precision of weights in mathematica NNs? AND how important is the precision of NN weights? i.e. how difficult does the problem you're trying to solve need to be for it to really matter? Also can the limitations of 32bit weights be overcome by additional neurons & layers?

I ask because I'm trying to reproduce the results of someone's deep CNN used for analyzing extremely noisy signal data and I've been unable to for a very long time (tried just about everything, should mention that it still has trouble with no noise data too) and I just realized that tensorflow (what I'm using) doesn't support 64bit weights for Conv layers and they used mathematica so I want to know if it could be relevant.

Attached is example noisy signal data (but as I said there appears to be difficulty with zero-noise data also): 
[image: Example noisy signal data that we are trying to analyze]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find much about this online but what I did find indicates that weight precision [isn't very important](https://www.quora.com/Can-we-use-64-bit-floats-in-the-input-tensor-of-Deep-Neural-networks) for deep learning problems, and supposedly most problems could be solved with 8 bit weights under the right conditions.

So I've still got no idea why my network isn't working but it probably doesn't have to do with weight precision. Although if anyone disagrees with what I found please still let me know and I may give the answer to you.